# Oracle ORA_DBA group disabling

Tags: oracle, identity

I working in a IAG dept.
I need to disable access to Oracle from OS groups leaving only access via local accounts, at least from v$pwfile_users.

It's possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if its possible, but I do know it is an abysmally bad idea.  Membership in ORACLE_DBA (Windows group) is what allows OS authentication for local accounts.  Without it you would end up locking out the dba from doing his most critical tasks.  (BTW, no one knows what your 'IAG' department is, or the significance of your working in it).

Comment: Tkanks @EdStevens, IAG is acronym for Identity and Access Governance

Comment: ok.  So let me reiterate that what you are asking about is a terrible idea.  What you are proposing is cutting of the DBA's method of connecting when all else fails.  You could very well find your database completely locked down and inaccessible.

Comment: Just what do you think removing this group would accomplish?